# I'm using Google Drive Spreadsheets and need to create a report - how do I do this logical query?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-drive-api

I've got a spreadsheet that has the headings Operation, Priority and Specialty so all of the information for a specific operation is on one line and is stored as text.

I need to create a report for each Specialty that tells me the number of Operations done, which is easy (using COUNTIF), but also how many routine or urgent Priority Operations there were.

This would be easy in a database. I'd do it like this.

COUNT * FROM OPERATION_LIST
WHERE Specialty = "Cardiac"
AND Priority = "Routine";

I cannot for the life of me work out how to do this in Spreadsheet though.

I know Google Drive Spreadsheets have a QUERY function but I cannot work out how to use it for this and Googling for answers is no help. I'm sure it'll be obvious when I see it but I've been working on this for days now, with no luck.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you share a doc?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

=query(A:C, "select A,count(B) where B = 'Routine' and C = 'Cardiac' group by A label count(B) 'Count'",1)

Assuming that you have a header row (Operation, Priority, Speciality, which represent A,B,C in the query - respectively).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I sorted this out over a year ago!

Comment: Oops, okay. (There were no signs to indicate, that it's an out-of-date question :) )

Comment: Haha. Not problems. This was back when I'd only just started using StackExchange. I can't remember the solution (it's implemented now) as it's pretty long and complex.